# LinkedBlockingQueue peek at particular spot

Tags: java, queue

I have a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and I want to check if there is a certain order of elements in the queue without removing the elements. I was hoping there was method I could use to peek at a particular spot in the queue. For example, `queue.peekSpot(0)` would return the head and `quque.peekSpot(queue.size())` would return the tail. Right now I have this method but it removes the things it is reading. The queue is a type `char` by the way.

```
public boolean checkString(String string) {
    if (string.length() < 1) {
        return true;
    }
    char input = queue.take();
    if (input == string.charAt(0)) {
        return checkString(string.substring(1));
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I could use a `peekSpot()` method, this could be done as follows, greatly simplifying the code.

```
public boolean checkString(String string){
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        if(!(string.charAt(i) == queue.peekSpot(i))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Somebody might say, what if that spot doesn't exist? Well then it might wait for that spot to exist. I am using a queue instead of an ordinary string because this is a serial feed and the string would have to constantly change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to i.e access items by index. but You can call `toArray()`, which would return you an array and then you can access index locations. Something like this.

```
String peekSpot(Queue<String> queue, Integer index){
    if(queue == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Object[] array = queue.toArray();
    return (String)array[index];
}
```